# Generating a complicated data structure in a more efficient manner

Tags: ruby, array, hash-map

I need to convert some CSV data into a format recognizable by some old script my work uses. Changing the format is pretty much out of the question. So I've written this:

```
$rate_plan_terms = [
  "pp",
  "01",
  "12",
  "24",
  "36"
]

def generate(fname)
  puts "generating doc for #{fname}"
  file = File.open(fname)
  standard_offer_hash = {}
  features_hash = {}

  file.readlines[1..-1].each do |row|
    # standard_offers
    _region, offer_cid, _offer_code, offer_name, product_cid, product_name, component_name, component_cid = *row.split(",")
#used? no   yes        no          yes         kinda        yes           yes             yes

    standard_offer_hash[product_cid] ||= {}  
    standard_offer_hash[product_cid][:offerType] = product_name # just keep it as product_cid?
    standard_offer_hash[product_cid][:ratePlan] ||= []

    $rate_plan_terms.each do |term|
      rate_plan = {
        :ratePlanName       => offer_name,
        :ratePlanCode       => offer_cid,
        :ratePlanTerm       => term,
        :offerEffectiveDate => "",
        :ratePlanMRC        => ""
      }

      standard_offer_hash[product_cid][:ratePlan] << rate_plan unless standard_offer_hash[product_cid][:ratePlan].include? rate_plan # they will be repeated because of features
    end

    # features
    features_hash[component_cid] ||= {
      :featureName          => component_name,
      :featureCode          => component_cid,
      :featureType          => "FEATURE",
      :featureTerm          => "",
      :featureEffectiveDate => "",
      :featureMRC           => ""
    }

  end
  feature_arr = features_hash.map {|k,f| f}
  standard_offer_arr = standard_offer_hash.map {|k,o| o}
  product_arr = []

  pricelist = {
    :features => { :feature => feature_arr }
    :ChannelOrgType => "OCM",
    :Region => "ALL",
    :product => product_arr,
    :businessRelationship => "",
    :standardOffer => standard_offer_arr,
  }

  {:PriceList => pricelist}
end
```

Yeah, complicated. This is running on up to a million lines per file, usually two files, every day. So it needs to be faster than it currently is.

FYI, the CSV is loosely separated into many products belong to many offers, and products have many features, but two different products can have the same features. So there is a lot of repeating.

There seem to be two time sinks here. One is the `Array#include?` I'm running over and over again. I wanted to transform that into a `build hash -> convert to array later` approach I took with `features_arr` and `standard_offers_arr` to avoid doing searches. But it depends on the `product_cid`, which (could) change per row.

The second is those two hashes to arrays at the end. The `standard_offer_hash` is going to be *huge*. That's can't be very fast.

To be completely honest I just don't see a way to optimize this further. Any suggestions?

I can show some output for what the generated structure needs to look like, if it would help.

Comment: Is the idea to write the output to a file? Or just to have it in memory?

Comment: It needs to remain in memory to get passed into another function, which does some magical back-end stuff and then prints it to stdout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You open the file, but you don't explicitly close it. Bad karma.
- You read *all* lines into memory, it seems, rather than go through them one by one. Memory-wise that's pretty inefficient.
- Any reason for `$rate_plan_terms` to be global? That too seems like bad karma. A constant would make more sense, I think.
- Have you considered using Ruby's bundled CSV parser? It'll be more robust.
- It'd be easier to just use `Hash#values` rather than `map { |k, v| v }`

As for the use of `include?`, you skip that by making `:rate_plan` a hash, and use a key like `"#{offer_name}#{offer_cid}"`. Simpler to explain in code, so see below.

```
require "csv"

def generate(fname)
  puts "generating doc for #{fname}"

  terms = %w{pp 01 12 24 36}.freeze # just made this local here, a const would still be better
  offers = {}
  features = {}

  CSV.foreach(fname, headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
    # If the CSV file has a proper header line, you can also access cells by their name
    _region, offer_cid, _offer_code, offer_name, product_cid, product_name, component_name, component_cid = *row.fields

    offers[product_cid] ||= {
      offerType: product_name
      ratePlan: {}
    }

    key = "#{offer_name}#{offer_cid}"
    offers[product_cid][:ratePlan][key] ||= terms.map do |term|
      {
        ratePlanName: offer_name,
        ratePlanCode: offer_cid,
        ratePlanTerm: term,
        offerEffectiveDate: "",
        ratePlanMRC: ""
      }
    end

    features[component_cid] ||= {
      featureName: component_name,
      featureCode: component_cid,
      featureType: "FEATURE",
      featureTerm: "",
      featureEffectiveDate: "",
      featureMRC: ""
    }
  end

  offsers.each do |key, offer|
    offer[:ratePlan] = offer[:ratePlan].values
  end

  {
    PriceList: {
      features: { feature: features.values }
      ChannelOrgType: "OCM",
      Region: "ALL",
      product: [],
      businessRelationship: "",
      standardOffer: offers.values
    }
  }
end
```

Still not pretty (it's a tad over the 5-10 line limit you might strive for for methods in Ruby).

It might be nice to break things into methods like `feature_hash(name, cid)`, which would generate the separate hashes.

```
require "csv"

TERMS = %w{pp 01 12 24 36}.freeze

def generate(fname)
  puts "generating doc for #{fname}"

  offers = {}
  features = {}

  CSV.foreach(fname, headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
    # If the CSV file has a proper header line, you can also access cells by their name
    _region, offer_cid, _offer_code, offer_name, product_cid, product_name, component_name, component_cid = *row.fields

    offers[product_cid] ||= {
      offerType: product_name
      ratePlan: {}
    }

    key = "#{offer_name}#{offer_cid}"
    offers[product_cid][:ratePlan][key] ||= rate_plan_array(offer_name, offer_cid)

    features[component_cid] ||= feature_hash(component_name, component_cid)
  end

  offsers.each do |key, offer|
    offer[:ratePlan] = offer[:ratePlan].values
  end

  {
    PriceList: {
      features: { feature: features.values }
      ChannelOrgType: "OCM",
      Region: "ALL",
      product: [],
      businessRelationship: "",
      standardOffer: offers.values
    }
  }
end

def rate_plan_array(name, cid)
  TERMS.map do |term|
    {
      ratePlanName: offer_name,
      ratePlanCode: offer_cid,
      ratePlanTerm: term,
      offerEffectiveDate: "",
      ratePlanMRC: ""
    }
  end
end

def feature_hash(name, cid)
  {
    featureName: name,
    featureCode: cid,
    featureType: "FEATURE",
    featureTerm: "",
    featureEffectiveDate: "",
    featureMRC: ""
  }
end
```

Either way you cut it, though, it probably won't win any beauty contests.

Comment: This has a lot of great suggestions. Your solution to cycle through offers to fix the :rateplan class is great for what I was looking for.

Comment: `terms` being global was an artifact of old code, but even then it was inappropriate.